# Unsure how to model and architecture this one

Tags: c#, architecture

I have got a problem here and I am banging my head against the wall.

I have an object that is part of my model. Lets call it MyObject. It has the following properties:

- Property1
- Property2
- Property3
- Property4.1
- Property4.2
- Property4.3

The first three properties are independent. 4th, 5th and 6th belong together, they are a set, lets call it the Properties4Set.

The Properties4Set is dependant on property1, 2 and 3.
so if any of these values changes the whole set must be recalculated.

The calculation works the following way:
I have got a file where i have a mapping between Property1 and a default Properties4Set.
So based on Property1 I must load this default set, and after that apply the rules for Property2 and 3.

I have kind of a mvvm application going on here. I made a repository that can create me my domain objects and return it with the correct values. 
My problem starts once I want to change Property1. Because that means I need a new default Properties4Set.

At the moment I see two options to handle that.

Option1:
Implement a "GetNewDefaultSet(property1)" method into the repository and inject the repository into MyObject. Once Property1 changes, load a new set from the repository, and recalculate the values based on 2 and 3.

Option2:
Implement a "GetAllDefaultSets()" method into the repository and inject the whole collection of Properties4Sets into MyObject. Once Property1 changes, load the appropriate set from the list.

I went for option1 first but then read that it is bad design if you inject the repository into your domain objects. They should not care about how to get the data they need.
My Problem with option2 is that it seems kind of an overkill to inject the whole list of sets if the object only needs one set at a time.

so, how would handle that? do you see another option?

**EDIT**

> It is bad that you has no concrete implementation example there.

ok here is some code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Just a DTO for how the set is actually stored, can be fetched from the repository
/// </summary>
public class MySetMapping
{
    private int value1;
    private float value4;
    private float value5;
    private float value6;

    public MySetMapping(int value1, float value4, float value5, float value6)
    {
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value4 = value4;
        this.value5 = value5;
        this.value6 = value6;
    }

    public int Value1
    {
        get { return this.value1; }
    }

    public float Value4
    {
        get { return this.value4; }
    }

    public float Value5
    {
        get { return this.value5; }
    }

    public float Value6
    {
        get { return this.value6; }
    }
}
```

he is the set class:

```
public class MySet
{
    private float value4;
    private float value5;
    private float value6;

    public MySet(float value4, float value5, float value6)
    {
        this.value4 = value4;
        this.value5 = value5;
        this.value6 = value6;
    }

    public float Value4
    {
        get { return this.value4; }
    }

    public float Value5
    {
        get { return this.value4; }
    }

    public float Value6
    {
        get { return this.value4; }
    }
}
```

and here the actual object that i need:

```
/// <summary>
/// the main business object, has actually more properties
/// </summary>
public class MyObject
{
    private int value1;
    private int value2;
    private int value3;
    private MySet mySet;

    public MyObject(int value1, int value2, int value3)
    {
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value2 = value2;
        this.value3 = value3;

        //needs something to get the correct set for the three values
    }

    public int Value1
    {
        get { return this.value1; }
        set
        {
            this.value1 = value;
            //adjust set
        }
    }

    public int Value2
    {
        get { return this.value2; }
        set
        {
            this.value2 = value;
            //adjust set
        }
    }

    public int Value3
    {
        get { return this.value3; }
        set
        {
            this.value3 = value;
            //adjust set
        }
    }

    public float Value41
    {
        get
        {
            return this.mySet.Value4;
        }
    }

    public float Value42
    {
        get
        {
            return this.mySet.Value5;
        }
    }

    public float Value43
    {
        get
        {
            return this.mySet.Value6;
        }
    }
```

maybe you can now understand it better.

Comment: If you have several properties that depend on each other and are somewhat related, doesn't that ring any bells for you? Shouldn't it be a separate class? A nice example is address - street, city, etc... You won't store that separately as fields of an user, right? Isn't it similar to your scenario?

Comment: actually i already separated 4.1, 4.2, 4.3 into another class. but that does not change my question. because now I still have to get the correct object for property1 from somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is bad that you has no concrete implementation example there. It is hard to imagine what is Property4Set, or how it got the data from repository. What happen when the Property2 or 3 changed. What is that you expect for Default Value.

From the current information, still dependending on the situation, I think the builder pattern is good for you.

Example:

```
public class MyObjectBuilder{
  // inject the repository
  public MyObjectBuilder(IMyObjectBuilderRepository repository) 

  private Property1 property1;
  public void SetProperty1(Property1 prop){}

  public MyObject GetMyObject(){
    MyObject result = new MyObject(); // optional to use constructor injection
    result.Property1 = this.property1;

    // based on this.property1, set the Property4Set object
    Property4Set property4 = repository.GetProperty4Set(this.property1);

    result.Property4 = property4;
    return result;
  }
}
```